# How to fetch the selection of pop-up menu and then zoom out?

Tags: menu, popup, selection, dashcode

How can I fetch the selection of a pop-up menu after the user has selected "his" item and then pressed "Done"?

The selected can be displayed with:

```
 var clicked = document.getElementById("popup").value;
```

alert(clicked);

And, how can I zoom out, after this item has been selected?

Answer (score 0):

I have put a "ChangeHandler" on the pop-up men

```
function myChangeHandler(event) {

var clicked = document.getElementById("popup").value;
alert(clicked);
```

}

BR,

Stefan